# Subsets that contain the empty subset

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Enderton's book *Elements of set theory*.

Example 2, first chapter $\phi$ is the empty subset:

$\lbrace \phi\rbrace\in\lbrace\lbrace\phi\rbrace\rbrace$, but  $\lbrace \phi\rbrace\nsubseteq\lbrace\lbrace\phi\rbrace\rbrace$.

Why the second statement is not true? We know that  $\phi\subseteq A$, where $A$ is any subset, but why $\phi\in A$ is false?

What is the intuitive answer?

Comment: $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ is a set containing exactly one element, and that element is $\{\emptyset\}$ just the same as $\{a\}$ is a set containing exactly one element, namely $a$.  In the same way that $\{a\}$ does not contain the element $b$ (*where $a$ is considered different than $b$*) the set $\{\{\emptyset\}\}$ does not contain $\emptyset$ as *an element* (*despite having it as a subset*).  Having something as an element is different than having something as a subset.

Comment: I assume the $A$ that you ask about is $\{\{\phi\}\}$.  This set has exactly one member, namely $\{\phi\}$, because this is the only thing named between the outermost braces.  The one member of $A$, $\{\phi\}$, is not $\phi$, and therefore $\phi$ is not a member of $A$.  (If you wonder why $\{\phi\}$ is not $\phi$, notice that $\{\phi\}$ has a member, namely $\phi$, whereas $\phi$ has no members.)

Comment: Perhaps part of the frustration is that you might be thinking of looking as many layers down as you like, but we are only looking one layer down.  The set $\{\{a,b\},c\}$ for example contains exactly two elements, the first element is $\{a,b\}$ and the second element is $c$, however $\{\{a,b\},c\}$ does not contain the element $a$ (*despite it appearing several layers down*).

Comment: subsets aren't elements.  {{emptyset}} has one element.  It is {emptyset} which is not emptyset.  {emptyset} has one element.  It *is* emptyset.  So {emptyset} has an element that {{emptyset}} does not.  Consider emptyset = a.  And consider {a} = b.  Then $\{a\} \not \subset \{b\}$ because {a} has an elemet that {b} does not.

Comment: It's abstract but sets are collections of things and are not the things themselves.  My house is a collection of many things.  Two of those things are my two cats; fleabottom and gunkbert.  But {fleabottom, gunkber} is a collection.  That is not something that is in my house.  But {fleabottom, gunkbert} is a subcollect of my things.  So is the emptyset.  But nowhere in my houst do I actually *have* the emptyset.